# ajax succuss function not working but showing in the firebug console

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating simple search.

This is work perfect without using ajax and I did it with ajax.

In **firebug console** showing the response array but in ajax success function does not trigger the data.why?

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php 
include('RO_dbconfig.php');
$search =$_GET['search'];

$sql=$dbconnect->prepare("SELECT student_name FROM student_reg WHERE reg_id='$search'");
$sql->execute();

$result=$sql->fetchALL();
var_dump($result);    
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#serachSubmit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data =$("#searchForm").serialize();
    //$("#response").html(data);
    $.ajax({            
        type:"GET",
        url:"search.php",
        data:data,

        succuss:function(e){
            alert(e);

            }           
        });     
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="searchForm" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label label_al" for="inputStNum">Student No:</label>

  <div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" id="searchText" class="span2 span11" name="search">
    <input type="submit" id="serachSubmit" class="btn buttnn" value="Search"/>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: It should be `success` not `succuss`

Comment: `succuss` => `success`

Comment: :facepalm: for the upvoter.

Answer (score 1):

**Misspelled**

Instead of `succuss:function(e){` write  `success:function(e){`

Answer (score 1):

Please look on your ajax code. It has a misspelled about **succuss**. Actually it will be **success**

**AJAX** : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$("#serachSubmit").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var data =$("#searchForm").serialize();
//$("#response").html(data);
$.ajax({            
    type:"GET",
    url:"search.php",
    data:data,

    success:function(e){
        alert(e);

        }           
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have typo here

replace

```
succuss:function(e)
```

with

```
 success:function(e)
```